# How Quartz Scheduler handle unexpected server crash or error while running jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am planning to use Quartz scheduler for my project and before pitch in i would like to have more grip, I would like to know how quartz scheduler will behave when server crashed or any other error happened while running jobs.

1. Does it resume the task where it stopped after restart the server ?
2. Does it update the status in JobStore?

Please throw me some light on these areas to understand more. Appreciate your help and many thanks in advance

Comment: `Does it resume the task where it stopped after restart the server ?` -> you can listen to failed jobs/catch exception and restart if required. `Does it update the status in JobStore?` yes it does. Quartz’s clustering features bring both high availability and scalability to your scheduler via fail-over and load balancing functionality.

Comment: See this for more: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/